# Windows Icons Font is missing

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

It seems my windows 10 icon font is missing or deleted.

How to restore? what is the name of the font?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: yeah several times

Comment: I just deleted some fonts and then this happened. But I just deleted none-windows fonts. just thinking if one of them was deleted wrong!

Comment: "I just deleted some fonts and then this happened." - Which fonts?  Have you tried using SFC and/or DISM to recover those files?

Comment: You can follow the article https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/119581-restore-default-font-settings-windows.html to restore default font settings

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for us to know what you have deleted.

Look for the font files in the Recycle Bin and restore them if found in there.

Otherwise, if you have System Restore enabled, try to rollback to a point
from before you deleted the fonts.

If all fails, I suggest to do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just copied fonts from other windows 10 to mine, and then it fixed :)